# asp:hidden not able to access in code behind

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have very little experience with jQuery and asp.net (VB).

What I am trying to achieve is this:
1. My page has few textboxes, and a panel containing three labels, a GridView and a HiddenField. 
2. When page loads hide panel
3. On the page, user clicks inside textbox and then presses F2 key 
4. jQuery senses the F2 key and extracts textbox class and value
5. Also HiddenField/HiddenBoxID value is set to textbox class
6. Trigger a button's click event
7. Now in code behind extract hiddenID value and do further procesing
8. Make panel visible

My jQuery looks something like this:

```
// Extract TextBox ID and Text Value
var currentClass = $(this).attr('Class');
var currentVal = $('.' + currentClass + '').val();
$('#HiddenBoxID').val(currentClass);
$("#helpButton").trigger('click');
```

My helpbutton code looks like this:

```
Dim HuntBoxID As String
HuntBoxID = HiddenBoxID.Value
```

Here is the problem, when the panel is set to visible=true then I am able to get HiddenBoxID value from jquery to code behind, but when I make the panel visible=false then I am not able to send value from jQuery to code behind. I don't know why? I am using chrome browser and in debug console (F12) I can see the value being set in currentClass and currentVal.
Can someone pls tell me how to achieve the above mentioned.
Also can someone tell me what I am doing wrong, Some code examples will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a control's `Visible` property to false, none of that control's HTML markup will be sent to the client. As far as the client is concerned, that control does not exist. You can verify by viewing the HTML source on the client.

Instead of manipulating the `Visible` property, use CSS styles. Here it is in C#, but the VB.NET syntax should be similar:

```
HiddenBoxID.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

When you manipulate it with CSS styles, the markup will still be sent to the client, and therefore you can later show the element using client side code. For example, with jQuery:

```
$('#HiddenBoxID').show();
```

Comment: I tried doing the same with the asp:panel, first I did display:none when the page load (in aspx itself) then,  as the page load is done I click inside textbox and then I call my jQuery function where i tried doing display:block, also did the same in code behind. the result of doing so was, I got the textbox class and textbox value in jQuery but when I accessed it in code behind it came up empty.

Comment: @Abb That may be unrelated, could be due to how you're loading the page. Hard to say, because you didn't provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I've done something like you are mentioning, specifically using client side javascript/jQuery... but my guess is that you are unable to get the client side ID because asp.net isn't even sending the control to the client since it is visible=false.

I could totally be wrong about this... but when you say you are immediately hiding the panel on page load...I assume you are doing that sever side in code behind, right?  Maybe try setting it to hidden in jQuery. In other words, ensure the control is getting sent to the client and then use jQuery to hide it immediately.

Another thing to look at is hit F12 and see if your hidden html is visible in the source on the client. If it isn't then asp.net isn't even sending the control to your client, hence why you can't get the client ID.